# Blank page when accessing Report Manager with end-user login on an end PC

Tags: reporting-services

I installed SQL Server 2008 Standard on Windows Server 2012, and configure the SSRS accordingly.

On an end PC, I use servername/reports to access Report Manager, after I put in a normal user's credential, it shows a page without any folders or reports[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxngR.png)

But if I login as a domain admin, then I can see all the folders and reports.

Any ideas why please?

Aiden

Comment: You need to give browser permissions to your users. Better assign permissions to user groups and add users to the groups

Comment: Hi Niktrs, I've already added ourdomain/domain users (a group that contains all of our users) for browser permission to every folder, I even added just one end-user for testing purpose. I also added the group and the user to the Site Settings, I've tried all of these prior coming to here, but none of them help.